# Update tensor value using `assign` function on tensor 2DIM

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have 2-dimensional tensor using `tf.Variable`, `[[10,9],[9,8]]`. So I can change it's value using index. In this case, I want to change **10** to **8**, then I wrote this code, using assign function.

```py
changeAbleTensor = tf.Variable([[10,9],[9,8]]);
changeAbleTensor[0][0].assign(10)
```

Code above, give me an error

> AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

But, when I change my code from `changeAbleTensor[0][0].assign(10)` to `changeAbleTensor[0,0].assign(10)` the **10** is changed to **8** successfully.

I'm wondering about that behavior, cause when I check the type of variable that using `[0][0]` and `[0,0]` it shows the same type.

```py
type(changeAbleTensor[0][0]), type(changeAbleTensor[0,0])
# result
# (tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor,
# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor)
```

Can you tell me why we `[0][0]` drive to error that said **EagerTensor doesn't have assign attribute** and on the other side `[0,0]` has assign attribute even though both has the same type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just an assumption**

Applying the slice operation on a `tf.Variable` will return a `Tensor` that inherits the method `assign` of `tf.Variable`. The problem is `changeAbleTensor[0][0]` is first slicing a `tf.Variable` and then slicing a `tf.Tensor` and thus you appear to lose the context of the `tf.Variable`. For example, when slicing once, both options have the **same** methods including `assign`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

changeAbleTensor = tf.Variable([[1,9],[9,8]]);

print(dir(changeAbleTensor[0]))
print(dir(changeAbleTensor[0,0]))
```

```
['OVERLOADABLE_OPERATORS', '_USE_EQUALITY', '__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__array__', '__array_priority__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__complex__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__long__', '__lt__', '__matmul__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__or__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmatmul__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__tf_tracing_type__', '__truediv__', '__weakref__', '__xor__', '_add_consumer', '_as_node_def_input', '_as_tf_output', '_c_api_shape', '_copy', '_copy_nograd', '_copy_to_device', '_create_with_tf_output', '_datatype_enum', '_disallow_bool_casting', '_disallow_in_graph_mode', '_disallow_iteration', '_disallow_when_autograph_disabled', '_disallow_when_autograph_enabled', '_disallow_when_autograph_unavailable', '_handle_data', '_id', '_matmul', '_num_elements', '_numpy', '_numpy_internal', '_numpy_style_getitem', '_override_operator', '_prefer_custom_summarizer', '_rank', '_shape', '_shape_as_list', '_shape_tuple', '_summarize_value', '_tensor_shape', '_tf_api_names', '_tf_api_names_v1', '_with_index_add', '_with_index_max', '_with_index_min', '_with_index_update', 'assign', 'backing_device', 'consumers', 'cpu', 'device', 'dtype', 'eval', 'experimental_ref', 'get_shape', 'gpu', 'graph', 'is_packed', 'name', 'ndim', 'numpy', 'op', 'ref', 'set_shape', 'shape', 'value_index']
['OVERLOADABLE_OPERATORS', '_USE_EQUALITY', '__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__array__', '__array_priority__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__complex__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__long__', '__lt__', '__matmul__', '__mod__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__or__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmatmul__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__tf_tracing_type__', '__truediv__', '__weakref__', '__xor__', '_add_consumer', '_as_node_def_input', '_as_tf_output', '_c_api_shape', '_copy', '_copy_nograd', '_copy_to_device', '_create_with_tf_output', '_datatype_enum', '_disallow_bool_casting', '_disallow_in_graph_mode', '_disallow_iteration', '_disallow_when_autograph_disabled', '_disallow_when_autograph_enabled', '_disallow_when_autograph_unavailable', '_handle_data', '_id', '_matmul', '_num_elements', '_numpy', '_numpy_internal', '_numpy_style_getitem', '_override_operator', '_prefer_custom_summarizer', '_rank', '_shape', '_shape_as_list', '_shape_tuple', '_summarize_value', '_tensor_shape', '_tf_api_names', '_tf_api_names_v1', '_with_index_add', '_with_index_max', '_with_index_min', '_with_index_update', 'assign', 'backing_device', 'consumers', 'cpu', 'device', 'dtype', 'eval', 'experimental_ref', 'get_shape', 'gpu', 'graph', 'is_packed', 'name', 'ndim', 'numpy', 'op', 'ref', 'set_shape', 'shape', 'value_index']
```

whereas:

```
print(dir(changeAbleTensor[0][0]) == dir(changeAbleTensor[0,0]))
```

returns `False`, since the `assign` method is no longer there.

Comment: Thank you sir.. it's clear explenation